# Error when installing PHP70 with Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, php-7, laravel-valet

When I try to install PHP7 with Homebrew I get this error

```
Sorry, I cannot run apxs.  Possible reasons follow:

1. Perl is not installed
2. apxs was not found. Try to pass the path using --with-apxs2=/path/to/apxs
3. Apache was not built using --enable-so (the apxs usage page is displayed)

The output of /usr/sbin/apxs follows:
apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.

configure: error: Aborting
```

And the command I've used to install it is :

```
brew install homebrew/php/php70
```

Here's a screenshot of my terminal:

[Terminal Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMRNl.png)

Does any one have a solution for this, knowing that I've searching the web for a solution without any luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you're upgrading:

`brew reinstall php70 --without-apache`

otherwise if you're installing php70 for the first time, try the following::

`brew install home-brew/php/php70 --without-apache`

Faced a similar issue, found it under this GitHub issue: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3283